# saspy: write large SAS table to local csv

Tags: python, csv, sas, saspy

The SASData object has `to_csv` and `to_df_CSV` methods, but both of these write to locations on the host machine (where the SAS session is running). Is there a way to write a large SAS data table to .CSV on my local machine from a remote connection? The option on the saspy Github page was to get the DataFrame, via `to_df`, and then write that to .CSV, but this won't work in my case because the SAS table is bigger than memory. Must I read and write in chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting.

```
tom64-3> python3.5
Python 3.5.5 (default, Feb  6 2018, 10:56:47)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import saspy
>>> sas = saspy.SASsession(cfgname='iomjwin')
SAS Connection established. Subprocess id is 3681

No encoding value provided. Will try to determine the correct encoding.
Setting encoding to cp1252 based upon the SAS session encoding value of wlatin1.
>>> sas
Access Method         = IOM
SAS Config name       = iomjwin
WORK Path             = C:\Users\sastpw\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD20052_d10a626_\Prc4\
SAS Version           = 9.04.01M4P11142016
SASPy Version         = 2.4.3
Teach me SAS          = False
Batch                 = False
Results               = Pandas
SAS Session Encoding  = wlatin1
Python Encoding value = cp1252
SAS process Pid value = 20052


>>> cars = sas.sasdata('cars', 'sashelp')
>>> cars.head()
    Make           Model   Type Origin DriveTrain   MSRP  Invoice  EngineSize  \
0  Acura             MDX    SUV   Asia        All  36945    33337         3.5
1  Acura  RSX Type S 2dr  Sedan   Asia      Front  23820    21761         2.0
2  Acura         TSX 4dr  Sedan   Asia      Front  26990    24647         2.4
3  Acura          TL 4dr  Sedan   Asia      Front  33195    30299         3.2
4  Acura      3.5 RL 4dr  Sedan   Asia      Front  43755    39014         3.5

   Cylinders  Horsepower  MPG_City  MPG_Highway  Weight  Wheelbase  Length
0          6         265        17           23    4451        106     189
1          4         200        24           31    2778        101     172
2          4         200        22           29    3230        105     183
3          6         270        20           28    3575        108     186
4          6         225        18           24    3880        115     197
>>> cars.to_csv(sas.workpath+'\cars.csv')
11                                                                                                                       The SAS System                                                                                         11:15 Tuesday, February 19, 2019


99
100        options nosource;


NOTE: The file X is:
      Filename=C:\Users\sastpw\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD20052_d10a626_\Prc4\cars.csv,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=32767,File Size (bytes)=0,
      Last Modified=19Feb2019:11:16:58,
      Create Time=19Feb2019:11:16:58

NOTE: 429 records were written to the file X.
      The minimum record length was 68.
      The maximum record length was 123.
NOTE: There were 428 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CARS.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.02 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


428 records created in X from SASHELP.CARS.


NOTE: "X" file was successfully created.
NOTE: PROCEDURE EXPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           1.49 seconds
      cpu time            0.21 seconds


>>> res = sas.download('/u/sastpw', r'C:\Users\sastpw\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD20052_d10a626_\Prc4\cars.csv')
>>> print(res['LOG'])
19                                                                                                                       The SAS System                                                                                         11:15 Tuesday, February 19, 2019


278
279        filename _sp_updn 'C:\Users\sastpw\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD20052_d10a626_\Prc4\cars.csv' recfm=F encoding=binary lrecl=4096
280
281
20                                                                                                                       The SAS System                                                                                         11:15 Tuesday, February 19, 2019


284
21                                                                                                                       The SAS System                                                                                         11:15 Tuesday, February 19, 2019


287
288        filename _sp_updn;
NOTE: Fileref _SP_UPDN has been deassigned.
289
290
>>>
SAS Connection terminated. Subprocess id was 3681
tom64-3> ll /u/sastpw/cars.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 sastpw r&d 38142 Feb 19 11:18 /u/sastpw/cars.csv
tom64-3>
tom64-3> head /u/sastpw/cars.csv
Make,Model,Type,Origin,DriveTrain,MSRP,Invoice,EngineSize,Cylinders,Horsepower,MPG_City,MPG_Highway,Weight,Wheelbase,Length
Acura,MDX,SUV,Asia,All,"$36,945","$33,337",3.5,6,265,17,23,4451,106,189
Acura,RSX Type S 2dr,Sedan,Asia,Front,"$23,820","$21,761",2,4,200,24,31,2778,101,172
Acura,TSX 4dr,Sedan,Asia,Front,"$26,990","$24,647",2.4,4,200,22,29,3230,105,183
Acura,TL 4dr,Sedan,Asia,Front,"$33,195","$30,299",3.2,6,270,20,28,3575,108,186
Acura,3.5 RL 4dr,Sedan,Asia,Front,"$43,755","$39,014",3.5,6,225,18,24,3880,115,197
Acura,3.5 RL w/Navigation 4dr,Sedan,Asia,Front,"$46,100","$41,100",3.5,6,225,18,24,3893,115,197
Acura,NSX coupe 2dr manual S,Sports,Asia,Rear,"$89,765","$79,978",3.2,6,290,17,24,3153,100,174
Audi,A4 1.8T 4dr,Sedan,Europe,Front,"$25,940","$23,508",1.8,4,170,22,31,3252,104,179
Audi,A41.8T convertible 2dr,Sedan,Europe,Front,"$35,940","$32,506",1.8,4,170,23,30,3638,105,180
tom64-3>
```

Comment: And, if for some reason, you couldn't use the latest version w/ the download() method,you could still accomplish this with the existing to_df_CSV() method, though it's a kludge and I wouldn't really suggest this, to_df_CSV takes 2 optional parameters; the local file to create (the .csv file copied over from the server), and whether to keep or delete that local csv file.

Comment: Again, you can't hit enter :(       here's the signature 
to_df_CSV(tempfile: str = None, tempkeep: bool = False, **kwargs) → pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: Arrg, 

so you can do this with your current version
try:
   cars.to_df_CSV('/u/sastpw/cars.csv', keeptemp=True)
except:
   pass

That will get the same first 2 steps as to_csv and download and catch the abend trying to create the data frame, leaving the local csv file.

Of course this is a hack, but it would work. I still suggest getting 2.4.3 and using download() though.
Tom

Comment: sorry, new to this. I'll attempt to format this and see if it works:
```
try:
   cars.to_df_CSV('/u/sastpw/cars.csv', keeptemp=True) 
except: 
   pass
```
hope that works

Comment: Thanks @Tom, download() is exactly what we're looking for. I had considered the try-except using to_df_CSV(), but it would try to fill up memory before failing, and this code is to be used by others and not only myself. I'll see if I can get 2.4.3, otherwise I can copy the code into a local function for the time being. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With saspy V2.4.3, you could try to_csv() to create the csv file on the SAS server, then download(), which is new in 2.4.3, to pull the csv over to your local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I've been looking into the saspy code. to_csv() let's you create a csv file on the remote machine, but to_df_CSV() (or its helper function sasdata2dataframeCSV()) actually seem to write the csv to my local machine from the remote session. The issue with this function is that it crashes when it executes its final portion, pd.read_csv(), which then causes an out-of-memory error on large datasets. I was looking for a way to stop building the pd.DataFrame, or just move the csv writing to a new function, but I don't completely understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, to_CSV() runs on the SAS server to write the SAS Data Set to the Servers filesystem as a .csv file. The to_df_CSV is to pull the SAS data Set over as a data frame into python, as you see. to_df() and to_df_CSV() are just 2 different mechanisms to move SAS data to Python as a data frame.

Comment: Whoops, can't hit enter here apparently. In the current version of saspy 2.4.3, there's a new method that you can try to do what you want. Use to_csv() to write the SAS Data Set out as a .csv file on the server, then use the download() method (off the SASsession object) to download that csv file from the server file system to your local filesystem (where saspy is running). It's just a file copy, not pandas or anything in python. It sounded like that's what you were trying to do.